# How compute the union of two C++ arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to make the union ("U") operation linking the different words from two arrays in one array, but it doesn't work. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

This is my Union function:

```
#define N 19

void CalcularUnion (tConjunto X, tConjunto Y, tConjunto* Z)
{
    int i, j, k;
    strcpy((*Z).Nombre, X.Nombre);
    strcat((*Z).Nombre, "U");
    strcat((*Z).Nombre, Y.Nombre);

    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        strcpy((*Z).Elementos[i], " ");
    }

    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        if(strlen(X.Elementos[i]) != 0)
        {
            strcpy((*Z).Elementos[i], X.Elementos[i]);
        }

        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    for(j=0; j<N; j++)
    {
        if(strlen(Y.Elementos[j]) != 0)
        {           
            for(k=0; k<N; k++)
            {
                if(strcmp(Y.Elementos[j], X.Elementos[k]) == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }

                else
                {
                    strcpy((*Z).Elementos[i], Y.Elementos[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ImprimirConjunto(*Z); //To print the result
}
```

The `tConjunto X` is an array that contains: `Andalucia, Catalunia, Canarias`
The `tConjunto Y` is an array that contains: `Extremadura, Asturias`
The `tConjunto Z` should be the result.

In this case the result should be: `tConjunto Z --> Andalucia, Catalunia, Canarias, Extremadura, Asturias.` But the program should check if one of the words on the first array (X) is on the second and omit it.

Can anyone help me?
Thank you!

Comment: Use `std::string`. Thank me later.

Comment: Can you show the definition of `tConjunto`, and especially if `Elementos` is an (unitialized) `char*` pointer or if it is an array of char that doesn't need allocation.  By the way, if you decide to apply Emerald Weapon's recommendation, you can thank him and you won't need an answer anymore ;-)

Comment: You should also pass `X` and  `Y` by reference, preferable const reference so that these big arrays of strings don't get copied.  Better perf:  `void CalcularUnion (tConjunto &X, tConjunto &Y, tConjunto* Z)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using C++, we can use `std::string` and `std::unordered_set`.  Insert each string from `X` and `Y` into a set.  Duplicates are implicitly filtered out.  Then enumerate over the unique items in the set and copy into your `Z` structure.

```
#include <unordered_set>

std::unordered_set<std::string> items;

// copy all the strings from X and Y into a set
// duplicates will not get inserted into this collection
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
     std::string str;
     str = X.Elementos[i];
     items.insert(str);
     str = Y.Elementos[i];
     items.insert(str);
}

// copy all the strings back into Z
int j = 0;
for (auto itor = items.begin(); itor != items.end(); itor++)
{
    std::string str = *itor;
    if (!str.empty())
    {
        // copy to your Z structure
        strcpy(Z->Elementos[j], str.c_str());
        j++;
        if (j >= N) // I'm assuming that Elementos has a max capacity of N items, you can change as appropriate
        {
            break; 
        }
    }
}
```